# How do I get data from Hive Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I'm currently working on a project which is sudoku and the UI and the game page everything else is completed except database. The problem is when user is logged in he can play the game but the user's data isn't stored. Login details are stored in a different model and I've created two models for game data and sign up info. It is stored locally. Now I need to parse the data to the user and need to access it when the user comeback or when the app is restarted.

I have already created the a model for game data which is

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class GameDataModel extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String star;

  @HiveField(1)
  final String avatar;

  @HiveField(2)
  final String saveGame;

  GameDataModel({
    required this.star,
    required this.avatar,
    required this.saveGame,
  });
```

And the login model is

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class LoginModel extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  int? uid;

  @HiveField(1)
  final String username;

  @HiveField(2)
  final String password;

  LoginModel({
    this.uid,
    required this.username,
    required this.password,
  });
```

Now what I need is there is stars, avatar and game data for users. After completing a level I need to store the collected stars to the user id and save it. How do I do that?

Comment: can you clarify more what exactly you want to achieve, and where you find a problem ?

Comment: https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/

Comment: @Gwhyyy the problem is I'm trying to save sign up information locally and trying to get that sign up info when the user is login but some how it isn't working

Comment: can you share the code that is not working when you try to save data

Comment: @Gwhyyy well the code is on my github here is the link to it https://github.com/AdeenT/Sudoku-Flutter.git         the code which is not working are on the file db.dart and login_page.dart

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize all created Models with their Adapters and a uniqe typeId. You are doing that in your **main.dart** but some of them are disabled

```
    Future<void> main() async {
 await Hive.initFlutter();
  // if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(LoginModelAdapter().typeId)) {
  //   Hive.registerAdapter(LoginModelAdapter());
  // }
  //  if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(GameDataModelAdapter().typeId)) {
  //   Hive.registerAdapter(GameDataModelAdapter());
  // }
  if(!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(UserModelAdapter().typeId)){
    Hive.registerAdapter(UserModelAdapter());
  }
  allData = await Hive.openBox('user model');
  //  gameDataDb = await Hive.openBox('user_db');
  //  loginDb = await Hive.openBox('user_db');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Should look like:

```
    Future<void> main() async {
 await Hive.initFlutter();
   if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(LoginModelAdapter().typeId)) {
     Hive.registerAdapter(LoginModelAdapter());
   }
    if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(GameDataModelAdapter().typeId)) {
     Hive.registerAdapter(GameDataModelAdapter());
   }
  if(!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(UserModelAdapter().typeId)){
    Hive.registerAdapter(UserModelAdapter());
  }
  allData = await Hive.openBox('user model');
  //  gameDataDb = await Hive.openBox('user_db');
  //  loginDb = await Hive.openBox('user_db');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

You are also using the same typeId (1) for your UserModel and your GameDataModel. Because so, the UserModelAdapter never gets Registered and you are not able to store any Data.

Change your UserModel typeId from 1 to 2 and it works fine.

@HiveType(typeId: 1) -> @HiveType(typeId: 2)

Answer (score 0):

Add below packages to your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  hive_generator: ^2.0.1
  build_runner: ^2.2.0
```

Next you need to define you entity class

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

part 'task_entity.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 2)
class Task {
  Task({required this.title, required this.content});

  @HiveField(0)
  String title;

  @HiveField(1)
  String content;
}
```

write this part of code **part 'task_entity.g.dart';** this is require to create custom type class to store data.

Next open terminal and write **flutter packages pub run build_runner build**
at the end of terminal work you'll see auto generated class

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'task_entity.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class TaskAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Task> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 2;

  @override
  Task read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return Task(
      title: fields[0] as String,
      content: fields[1] as String,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Task obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.title)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.content);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is TaskAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

Now you have to define adapter which is pair with your custom class.

```
void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter<Task>(TaskAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Task>('taskBox');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

After it , everything is prepare to store custom class. lets check out last part .

```
void _storeData(
      {required String title, required String content}) async {
    var box = Hive.box<Task>('taskBox');
    Task task = Task(content: content, title: title);
    await box.add(task);
  }
```

**TADA jobs done** .